# Calculating radioactive decay

Tags: homework-and-exercises, radioactivity, half-life

I was given the following word problem:

> If the half-life of a certain isotope is four years, what a fraction of a sample of that isotope will remain after 12 years?

This was simple for me. 12 years is equivalent to exactly 3 half-lives therefore 1/8 of the original sample amount remains.

But then I thought, what if a “non half-life” amount time passes? Not just like a different amount of years, but like months or days or something.

For example, if half of a half-life passes, does that mean 3/4 of the original sample remains?

Comment: You *are* familiar with the [exponential formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-life#Formulas_for_half-life_in_exponential_decay), right?

Comment: I forgot about this. Thanks for the refresher, it’s been a while

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a linear relationship, but a geometric (exponential) one, as you correctly suspected: after a time $t$ (expressed in the same unit as the half-life or period $T$), the remaining amount of non-decayed nuclei is:

$$N\  =\  N_0\  \frac{1}{2^{\left( t\  /\  T\right)  }}$$

Comment: Thanks. I forgot about this equation and someone else put a link to Wikipedia, but I appreciate the more in depth explanation here